# Show image instead of video on smaller screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-video, background-image

I have setup a background video on http://desertcinema.com/jheck/ with a help of [Device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js) library. In essence this library is supposed to change the background video to an image on smaller screens such as tablets and iPhones.

Here's my code so far:

```js
if( !device.tablet() && !device.mobile() ) {
    
  jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("#bgndVideo").on("YTPStart", function(){ jQuery("#eventListener").html("YTPStart")});
    jQuery("#bgndVideo").on("YTPEnd", function(){ jQuery("#eventListener").html("YTPEnd")});
    jQuery("#bgndVideo").on("YTPPause", function(){ jQuery("#eventListener").html("YTPPause")});
    jQuery("#bgndVideo").on("YTPBuffering", function(){ jQuery("#eventListener").html("YTPBuffering")});

    jQuery("#bgndVideo").mb_YTPlayer();

  });

} else {

  $('#bgimg').addClass('bg-image');

}
```

```css
.bg-image {
  background: url('http://koowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/new-york-city-streets-background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1 !important;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-position: center center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason when I resize the browser the video still appears on smaller screens.

How can I get an image to display instead of the video on smaller screens with abovementioned js library?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way more beautiful way to deal with this with media queries.

Media queries allow you to add some css to classes with conditions about the screen size.

For instance you can write :

```
@media (max-width : 762 px) {
   #someID{ font-size : 14px; 
               other properties : other values;
}
```

This way, you can detect when the screen is to little for your video. Then you have to know that property in your javascript too.

Thus, you can just do the following code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
var is_mobile = false;


if( $('#someID').css('display')=='none') {
    is_mobile = true;       
}

if (is_mobile == true) {
    /*
    / Add the script you want for mobile devices
    */

}
});
```

You can do that for tablets as well. In fact you can really personnalise that at the exact pixel you want, which is pretty more powerful than using the already existing functions.